# How to flatten list in java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

```
class Employee {
    private String name;
    private List<Employee> members;
}

List<Employee> emps = Arrays.asList(new Employee("A", Arrays.asList(
     new Employee("B", null),
     new Employee("C", null)
)))
```

The code to flatten the `List`:

```
List<Employee> total = 
    emps.stream()
        .flatMap(emp -> emp.members.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `total` `List` should have 3 elements, but it only has 2.

Comment: That type looks like a tree rather than a list ... or list of lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eran's answer is wrong, there is no `concat` on `Stream` instance. This should work:

```
emps.stream()
        .flatMap(emp -> Stream.concat(emp.members.stream(), Stream.of(emp)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[`Stream#concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution is:

```
List<Employee> total = emps.stream()
                      .collect(ArrayList::new,
                               (l, e) -> {l.add(e);l.addAll(e.getMembers());},
                               List::addAll);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your stream pipeline only returns the `Employee`s referenced by other `Employee`s. It doesn't keep the `Employee`s of the outer input `List`.

To get all the `Employee`s you can change your `flatMap` to concatenate the current `Employee` to the `Employee`s it references:

```
List<Employee> total = 
    emps.stream()
        .flatMap(emp -> Stream.concat(emp.members.stream(),Stream.of(emp)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or (if you prefer the outer `Employee` to come before the corresponding referenced `Employee`s):

```
List<Employee> total = 
    emps.stream()
        .flatMap(emp -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(emp),emp.members.stream()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that the result might contain duplicates. You can eliminate them by adding `distinct()` after `flatMap()` (assuming your `Employee` class overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()`).